# Plot line graphs c#, array

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am fairly new in c# (3 weeks), and StackOverflow, though by searching did not find anything which would satisfy my answer in this page yet.

How can one make a x^2 function to be plotted in c# (obviously I am not interested only in x^2 but any function of my choice)

This should be plotted in grid as a user application. Before that I would need to gather some data from a binary file which user would be selecting himself and I assume to pass these points to arrays so that I could be able to plot a graph.

Issues which I am not familiar with.

1. How can I use arrays (if possible) to plot a graph with the least amount memory usage? Any links, reference to learn would be useful.

   ```
   private void Pic1D_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       Line myLine = new Line();
       myLine.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightSteelBlue;
       myLine.X1 = 20;
       myLine.Y1 = 20;
       for (int i=0; i<=8; i++)
       { 
           myLine.X2 = i+20;
           myLine.Y2 = i*i+20;
           myLine.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
           myLine.StrokeThickness = 2;
           FunctionGrid.Children.Add(myLine);
           myLine.X2 = myLine.X1;
           myLine.Y2 = myLine.Y1;

       }
   }
   ```
2. Another issue I am trying to research: Is it possible to plot the above graph by using binary inputs in arrays? Mainly the x value would be represented in binary as well the y would be represent in binary. Is there a function, class which I could use in order to do this? I know how to convert this in binary content, though the file itself is a raw file. Ideally in the end I would want to use the below read in file to plot the function above in 2 D.

   ```
   if (NewDialogx.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
   {
       xPath.Text = NewDialogx.FileName;
   }

   byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@xPath.Text);
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   foreach (byte b in fileBytes)
   {
       count++;
       if (count > 4096)
       {
           sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(1, '!'));
           // GraphPlot[count-512,0,0] = Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
       }
   }

   File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\raiti\Desktop\NEW1", sb.ToString());
   ```

The below is how I tried to do this. I get this exception handling error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget.'

The issue is that I do not want to create this as list since this seems very impractical (though please do correct me) if I will need to plot around 10000+ data lines, and might take some space.

I hope I have been specific enough on this :).

Comment: "*I will need to plot around 10000+ data lines*" Hopefully not all at the same time. Your screen won't be large enough to see them all. Besides that, an efficient way of displaying curves is using Polylines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to put this in comments but there's way too much and I have some code to show.

I wouldn't usually worry about memory usage much, in a wpf application. This is presumably going to be running on a desktop and even the weaker end computers nowadays can cope with a shed load of graphics.

You should at least consider graphing software. There are a bunch of free  possibilities. I also wouldn't totally dismiss setting wpf aside and dumping the data to disk, charting in excel.

If this is sort of an academic exercise in that you only win if you use the least memory then I'd have to try the options and look at how much memory they use. 
The most efficient way to do graphics is supposed to be the various draw... options. You could draw lines into a picture. Although a bitmap has a fair bit of memory, you're potentially saving if you have many lines because the bitmap size won't go up whilst other approaches would use more memory.
You'd draw many lines using drawline, between each of the points.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms606810(v=vs.110).aspx
The following code (which I just happen to have to hand ) draws a set of lines on an image used as the overlay on the map here:
[image: GeneralStaff map editor]

```
    public static async Task<BitmapSource> GetGridImageAsync(FrameworkElement fe)
    {
        Matrix m = PresentationSource.FromVisual(fe)
            .CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;
        double dpiFactor = 1 / m.M11;
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {

            Pen GreyPen = new Pen(Brushes.Gray, 1 * dpiFactor);
            Pen GreyThickPen = new Pen(Brushes.Gray, 2 * dpiFactor);
            GreyPen.Freeze();
            int ix = 0;
            int iy = 0;
            int Width = 1155;
            int Height = 805;
            BitmapSource image = Visuals.CreateBitmap(
               Width, Height, 96,
                drawingContext =>
                {
                    int count = 0;
                    while (ix <= Width)
                    {
                        if (count % 5 == 0)
                        {
                            drawingContext.DrawLine(
                               GreyThickPen, new Point(ix, 0), new Point(ix, Map.Height - 1));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            drawingContext.DrawLine(
                                GreyPen, new Point(ix, 0), new Point(ix, Map.Height - 1));
                        }
                        ix += 35;
                        count++;
                    }
                    count = 0;
                    while (iy <= Width)
                    {
                        if (count % 5 == 0)
                        {
                            drawingContext.DrawLine(
                            GreyThickPen, new Point(0, iy), new Point(Map.Width -1, iy));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            drawingContext.DrawLine(
                            GreyPen, new Point(0, iy), new Point(Map.Width - 1, iy));
                        }
                        iy += 35;
                        count++;
                    }
                });
            return image;
        });
    }
}
```

fe is the window passed in and I use that scaling so the lines are crisp. It gives a factor of .8 on my machine.

That low level approach might not really be necessary for your purpose, in which case you could use polylines ( as Clemens suggested ).
A common way to present numerous things using wpf is to use an itemscontrol and bind the itemssource. You then template the data you bind into ui objects ( a polyline each in this case ). 
A polyline takes a pointcollection as it's Points property.
If your data is gathered and then doesn't change you can just bind that in a datatemplate like:

```
<Polyline Points="{Binding Points}" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" />
```

Where points is a public property presenting a pointcollection of some object you have for each row of your collection bound to itemssource.

If your lines are supposed to be curved then this is considerably more complicated. You can do Bezier curves using paths but you'd probably need to calculate based on your points.
At that point I'd be thinking again about using purpose built graphing software, personally.

2) Your array. You'd probably want to convert that to a pointcollection somewhere. That could be in a converter or in a viewmodel. MVVM ( and a viewmodel ) is the de facto standard pattern for wpf development.

3) Your error.
You get that when you try and use a piece of ui in two places. 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29964.wpf-tips-only-one-parent.aspx
Sometimes it doesn't error but also doesn't give you the expected result.
I think I'd need to see more code to work out exactly why.

Comment: It helped me move further thank you! I can't use excel as the files would come in binary raw data and in reality there will be TB of data. :)